# stopPropagation() stops propagation at wrong side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I ran into a problem while trying to create a non-click-through div.

Yes, its stops propagation, but stops what should not be stopped and doesn't stop what should be stopped

**js**

```
//screen has set stopPropagation

$("#smokeScreen").click(function(){
   event.stopPropagation();
})
```

**html**

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- lots of stuff that has to not be clickable while "smokeScreen is visible" -->
    <!-- lots of stuff that has to not be clickable while "smokeScreen is visible" -->
    <div id="smokeScreen">
        <!-- covers whole viewport -->

        <div id="form"><!-- another form stuff here --></div>
        <!-- covers whole viewport -->
    </div>

    <!-- lots of stuff that has to not be clickable while "smokeScreen is visible" -->
    <!-- lots of stuff that has to not be clickable while "smokeScreen is visible" -->
</div>
```

Funny thing is, that this code makes everything clickable, except the form...

So please, any tip?

And pointer-events:none; in css is not a solution, for some reason, it doesn't work as simple css, and I have not figured why yet, but I need to keep compatibility with older browser and this is very new statement.

Comment: @PranavCBalan Ya, on FF

Comment: Provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you binding any `form` descendants event or what?

Comment: actually, it is not a form like <form> .. it is only div with textbox and button, which is being processed by jquery. Look at it as simple divs. background should not be clickable, what is INSIDE smokescreen should.

Comment: with definiton of event (the post was deleted, dont know why) not working :( still what is behind smokeScreen is clickable and what is inside is not clickable 

$("#smokeScreen").click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});

Comment: BUT how do you bind `textbox, button` click? If you delegate it, be aware delegation use event bubbling, so... If you don't delegate event or even don't use any hanlder but just textbox or button don't react to user interaction, then see my second comment here (mcve)...

Comment: MCVE, get it, but still dont know, how more accurate I should be, I think, you are thinking in  more complicated way, ten my problem actually is. So again. I have 3 parts. One is the topmost div, which SHOULD BE CLICKABLE. Then there is a #smokescreen, which works as divider between my "form" and other stuff .. and then is the whole other page I made an image: http://screenshot.cz/JM13M/stopProp.png .... the black part should be clickable, the gray is smokescreen, on which is called the stopProp() and then the Lorem ipsum, which SHOULD NOT be clickable. Problem is, that lorem is and black not

Comment: If you click on any parents or sibling of `#smokeScreen`, then stopping propagation on `#smokeScreen` click won't stop these click handlers  (on parents, sibling) to be fired. You need to filter it in another way, e.g, check for `smokeScreen is visible` in these handlers. Again, if you fail to provide minimalistic sample replicating issue, what can i say?!

Answer (score 1):

So, what you seem to be missing here is that `stopPropagation()` prevents the event from being bubbled up to parent elements.

It **does not prevent** those elements, or any sibling elements from being clicked.

What you need to do is place an element covering the entire screen, then set the form `z-index` property to a higher value than that element so it is visible (Then there should be no need to call `stopPropagation()`).

Using your code, and inline styles, here is an example:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id='smoke_screen' style='z-index: 1000; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0' />
    <!-- lots of stuff that has to not be clickable while "smokeScreen is visible" -->
    <!-- lots of stuff that has to not be clickable while "smokeScreen is visible" -->
    <div id="smokeScreen">
        <!-- covers whole viewport -->
        <div id="form" style='z-index: 1001'><!-- another form stuff here --></div>
        <!-- covers whole viewport -->
    </div>

   <!-- lots of stuff that has to not be clickable while "smokeScreen is visible" -->
  <!-- lots of stuff that has to not be clickable while "smokeScreen is visible" -->
</div>
```